# Print the largest odd number

Tags: python, python-2.x

Ask user to input 10 integers and then print the largest odd number that was entered. If no odd number was entered, print a message to that effect.

I've written this code as my solution to the above exercise from chapter 2 of Computation and Programming Using Python by John Guttag. The book is meant to be used with Python 2.x. I need to know if the code can be "straightened up" in any way. So far, the book has covered variable assignment, print function, conditional branching, and loops.

```
largestOddNumber = None

for _ in range(10):  # '_' is a throw-away var
    number = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
    if number % 2 != 0 and number > largestOddNumber:
        largestOddNumber = number

print largestOddNumber or 'No odd number was entered.'
```

Comment: I don't think it's worth it for me to make an answer for this, but when you're writing a real program (not just an exercise) it's best to separate the input-output calls and the logic of the code. This code separates easily into two pieces:(1) Get 10 integers, and (2) calc the maximum. The code gets the 10 integers, passes them into a calculation function and then prints the return value with desired formatting. The calc function should have no Input/Output (that's all in the caller). So you separate the I/O from the logic.

Comment: Assuming your input is a list (like Snowbody suggested), you can do `max(number for number in input_list if number % 2 == 1)`. Almost as readable as plain English, compact, easy to maintain and reason about, and probably pretty fast

Answer (score 10):

Code looks good! I only have minor/pedantic comments:

```
for _ in range(10):  # '_' is a throw-away var
```

That comment is useless, the naming of the variable as `_` is sufficient to indicate that we don't intend on using it. Also, in python2.7, [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) returns a full list of all the values, which can get pretty inefficient as you go up, so you should prefer to use its lazier cousin, [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange):

```
for _ in xrange(10):
```

Then this:

```
print largestOddNumber or 'No odd number was entered.'
```

While I do like that `or` in python, rather than returning a bool returns the first argument that isn't `False`/`None`, it's a little difficult to read. Now, the code is perfectly correct for *odd* numbers but would actually be wrong for *even* numbers - if `0` ended up being the largest even number, we'd print the string. So I find it simpler to just be explicit:

```
if largestOddNumber is not None:
    print largestOddNumber
else:
    print 'No odd number was entered'
```

But really, the code is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is fine.

I have a few nitpick-style comments, that’s all:

- In this `if` condition:

  ```
  if number % 2 != 0 and number > largestOddNumber:
  ```

  I would turn the test for being odd into an affirmative one: `number % 2 == 1`, rather than a negation of the test for being even. I would also add parentheses around the two conditions – they’re not required by Python, but I think they often make code easier to read:

  ```
  if (number % 2 == 1) and (number > largestOddNumber):
  ```
- The Python style guide is [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which includes conventions for variable names.

  Variables should be named using `lowercase_with_underscores` (also called [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)), with the exception of classes, which use `CamelCase`. So your variable should really be `largest_odd_number`.
- If I don’t enter any odd numbers, I get an English sentence:

  ```
  No odd number was entered.
  ```

  whereas if I enter some numbers, I just get a number back:

  ```
  37
  ```

  It would be nice if I got an English sentence to describe the good output:

  ```
  The largest odd number entered was 37.
  ```

Finally, while I know you’re explicitly writing Python 2.x code, here’s a bit of advice for making this code future-proof for Python 3:

- In your if statement, you do a comparison between the user-entered number and None (until you set the variable `largest_odd_number`).

  Python 2 will let you mix types that way, and treats None as being less than all numbers, including `float(-inf)`. In Python 3, the same comparison would throw  a TypeError:

  ```
  Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 12 2015, 11:00:19)
  >>> None < 5
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
  ```

  You can expand the if statement to be more future-proof if you do a comparison to None first. This is also a little more explicit about how the program works, I think:

  ```
  if (number % 2 == 0) and \
     (largest_odd_number is None or number > largest_odd_number)
  ```

  That check would work on both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

You don't perform any input validation, so if I enter letters, or nothing at all, then you'll get errors. You could avoid this by wrapping the input in a `try except` and then looping over that until valid input is entered, like this:

```
for _ in range(10):  # '_' is a throw-away var
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print ("Please enter integers only.")
    if number % 2 != 0 and number > largestOddNumber:
        largestOddNumber = number
```

This way, if there's an error calling `int`, the user will be reminded to only enter integers. But if `int` runs correctly then it will reach the `break` statement and continue running with the valid input.

Comment: thank you. Please look at my follow-up code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105887/find-the-largest-odd-number-follow-up-code

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment here yet, but incorporating @snowbody's and @alexwlchan's answers, can you do this to future proof it?

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    input = raw_input

prompt = "Enter ten integers, separated by a space."
found_max = "The largest odd number entered was {}."
no_odds = "No odd number was entered."

ints = [int(i) for i in input(prompt).split()]
if len(ints) != 10:
    raise ValueError("Your input was not good.")

odds = [i for i in ints if i % 2]
print(found_max.format(max(odds)) if odds else no_odds)
```

Comment: it's okay..it still mixes IO and calculation in the same line (doesn't have a separate function for the calculation). Also, you can control the input better with a loop, something like `prompt = "Enter integer {} of ten."` `ints = [input(prompt.format(x)) for x in xrange(10)]`

Comment: @jeannassar, if i equals zero and because 0%2 equals zero, this even number gets into the list of odds

Comment: @srig, I just tried it. It does not. It only adds the number if `i % 2` is not equal to zero.

Comment: @Snowbody, what do you mean calculation here? The splitting and type conversion? I guess `odds = [int(i) for i in ints if int(i) % 2]` in this case.

Comment: @JeanNassar, I've just found out it only adds odds. Thank you

Comment: @JeanNassar I mean the line with the `print` does both IO and calculation (the `max(odds)`).